# Извлечение базы населённых пунктов (Название-широта-долгота) из OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

Есть задача получить базу вида "Название-широта-долгота" всех (до мельчайших сёл) населённых пунктов мира. Самая подробная и точная база из всех что я нашел у OpenStreetMaps. Но я никак не могу разобраться, как же её извлечь. И в вики Overpass API тоже об этом ничего не сказано.

Парсить planet.ost не могу, потому что даже для распаковки этого файла банально не хватит места.

Answer (score 1):

Запрос к Overpass вернет csv список.

```
[out:csv(name,::lat,::lon)][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Сахалин}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["place"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```